# summarizing time series dataset: extract time window sliding, change points, pattern seasonality in time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, automatic-summarization

I need to detect list of change points in time series dataset (temperature), and I need to split dataset into set of classes (patterns) and detect seasonality of each class (pattern). for example suppose that we create 2-classes named called and hot, each class contains readings that represent each state, I need to know seasonality of these state over the whole time period so that I can summarize dataset as hot state occurs from the time X to Y over month Z and from time ... to ... over month ... 
- it is preferable if there is a solution written in python/C++/C#

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are trying to detect seasonality in each of your two data sets. Here's a straightforward resource in Python, including example code:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-seasonality-with-python/ Here's one other resource I found helpful when I was learning about seasonality (it's in R):
https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/detecting-seasonality/